# conflict with java.util.Date and java.sql.TimeStamp

Tags: java, resultset

I am facing a unique problem.

I am querying a database field which has a datatype (in oracle) as DATE . I am retrieving the value from resultSet as rs.getObject("myDate") . We have two setups  which have  identical configuration . On one setup when I write rs.getObject("myDate").getClass() , I am geeting java.sql.TimeStamp and on another setup it is returning java.util.Date. The problem I am facing is when it returns an object of date it is ignoring the time and returning only the date part.

Comment: Are the database columns identical, type + length definition?

Answer (score 1):

I think this behaviour can be controlled using this connection property:

```
oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp
```

See this forum thread, for instance:

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=483903

Answer (score 0):

als info: java.sql.Timestamp IS a java.util.Date as it extends it.

Dates also have time, though it does not have nanoseconds, that's the only difference.

Sadly enough, that's the way it is implemented, but not the way it should be. From their own docs:

> The inheritance relationship between `Timestamp` and `java.util.Date` really denotes implementation inheritance, and not type inheritance.
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html

which means they were to lazy to write some encapsulation. This causes many quirks, like hashcodes not changing for nanoseconds and asymmetrical equals.